# Google Map Javascript API: Map without Google Places information

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i did not request the place library in the google map script, but poi information by Google is still showing up. I saw other examples where those poi are not shown. What is the right configuration to hide those poi?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done this before:

```
var myStyles =[
    {
        featureType: "poi",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
              { visibility: "off" }
        ]
    }
];

var myOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.42838,-2.9623),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: myStyles 
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```