# Remove existing labels from google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i have a application built using google map when a latitude and longitude is ploted over the map is there a way remove the markers which are already present in the map[image]

Comment: duplicate of [Google Map Javascript API: Map without Google Places information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062653/google-map-javascript-api-map-without-google-places-information/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 42.367112, lng: -71.080964},
    zoom: 16,
    styles: [
      {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [
          { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
      }
    ]
  });
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just go to Google Map Style Wizard, and turn of the points of interest visibility, and use the JSON to your map style.

in your map constructor, specify:

```
styles: [
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible in the Google Maps API using the following code .

```
[
    {
        featureType: 'all',
        elementType: 'labels',
        stylers: [{ 
            visibility: 'off' 
         }]
     }
]
```

Also check out this [StyleWizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html), for all info about styling your map.